# Android layout with wrap_content

Tags: android, layout, listitem

I'm trying to create a custom list item layout but I encountered an issue. See the example below :

Effective functioning

[image: Effective functioning]

The Issue

[image: The Issue]

The problem is when the green rectangle fills all the blue box (width set as `wrap_content`) because the green square disappeared. The square has to be right of the green rectangle but the size of this rectangle can change and I can't fix the green square to the right of the blue box.

The red rectangles are fixed and they aren't a problem.

I use some `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` to do this but it's not working as I wish.
I also can't use the `drawableRight` attribute because in the near future, there will be two icons (green square) instead of one.

If someone has already encountered this problem or has a way to solve this.

The wanted result is:

[[ListIconView] [[Some text here] [Icon]]< ..... blank space .....>[x] [y] [z]]

[[ListIconView] [[Long text from....... ] [Icon]]< . blank space ..>[x] [y] [z]]

[[ListIconView] [[A very long text from an older book....] [Icon]] [x] [y] [z]]

x, y and z are icons.

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: Please add the relevant layout files.

Comment: @Cylon Did you read answers?

Comment: @DamianKozlak Yes and it's not working! I'm thinking at create my own viewgroup!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that red square and rectangle are not the problem (probably parent layout is `RelativeLayout`), and you have `TextView` and `ImageView` as green rectangle and green square, use

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for your `TextView` (green rectangle)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text here" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20" 
        android:text="blablah"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="test string string string"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="String test"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I do above is that I assign space based on percentages for each of the item I want to fit in the root layout which is the LinearLayout, out of the total weightSum 100%. The ImageView will take 20% space, followed by another LinearLayout which will occupy 60%, and lastly the ImageButton which takes 20%, too